# Replacement for Wpantund deprecated

Tags: openthread

we are currently use NCP with wpantund.
we found out that the wpantund will deprecated.
what will replace it ? we are using Uart interface, so moving to any spi intrface will be a problem

Answer (score 1):

The replacement is [OpenThread Deamon](https://openthread.io/platforms/co-processor/ot-daemon).

Comment: 1.the OpenThread Deamon is for RCP only?  
2. what about NCP ? he also deprecated?  
3.the  OpenThread Deamon can support Uart ? i know that the RCP support SPI only.  
thanks

Comment: 1. OpenThread Daemon places most of OpenThread stack on host - it works with both RCP and NCP builds, but only a small subset of NCP functionality is used.
2. We continue to support NCP, but there is no guarantee that we will continue to introduce new features into NCP.
3. RCP is not SPI only - see the OpenThread Daemon link in the original reply above.

Answer (score 0):

wpantund and OpenThread NCP are live again and not marked as deprecated anymore. Nordic Semiconductor committed to develop and maintain them for OpenThread community for Thread 1.1 and Thread 1.2.